# Python/Django print loop progress along the way

Tags: python, wrapper, django-queryset, helper

Sometimes, while conducting long-running measurements in some loop in python, I have no clue when my measurements are going to finish.

So I needed a tool to print some progress along the way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time such measurement involves some heavy processing inside the main loop, so I developed a simple wrapper function that prints loop progress for any iterable:

```
from datetime import datetime
def print_progress(iterable, percent_step=1):
    total = float(len(iterable))
    # or 1 means that iterable has < 100 elems
    abs_step = int((total * percent_step)/100) or 1
    for i, obj in enumerate(iterable):
        if i and not i % abs_step:
             print "{0:.2%} processed, {1:%H:%M:%S}".format(i/total, datetime.now())
        yield obj
```

`percent_step` argument defines the granularity level of printing: each time the loop finished processing the `percent_step` % amount of data, the total percentage of processed data is printed on the screen.

Then can apply this wrapper to the loop:

```
for x in print_progress(my_list):
    # processing
    ...
```

The same iterator could be applied for *django querysets*, but calculating total object count before the loop could be expensive by itself, so in case of retrieving all objects from the database like *PostgreSQL* it is better to replace `len` with direct SQL:

```
"select reltuples from pg_class where relname='%s'" % table_name
```

#### Another variant that prints progress after the specified amount of seconds:

```
def print_progress(iterable, second_step=10):
    total = float(len(iterable))
    import time
    time1 = time.time()
    for i, obj in enumerate(iterable):
        if time.time() - time1 > second_step:
             print "{0:.2%} processed".format(i/total)
             time1 = time.time()
        yield obj
```